# In sheets, I need to sum each work week beginning on Wednesday and ending on Tuesday with the pay being paid multiple times on any day therein

Tags: sumproduct

Sum a payweek that is always Wednesday through Tuesday each week where the payments are made multiple times throughout that week on any day in that week, i.e., payments might be Thursday, Saturday, and Sunday only. Next week might be Wednesday,Friday, and Tuesday. So the day of the week of payments vary as do the number of payments in that week (once, twice, three times, etc).
I need something like weeknum where the day the week the week starts can be chosen (Wednesday). Can add a helper column if needed.

```
4835259 Mon 3/21    CINCINNATI  $8,000
5245716 Tue 3/22    HIGHLAND IL $2,500
5352002 Thu 3/24    LOUISVILLE  $4,475
5352016 Fri 3/25    NASHVILLE   $3,375
```

So in this example, I only want $4475 & $3375 summed. Most recent days of week Wednesday through Tuesday (Never including last Tuesday). As you can see, data is not necessarily entered for every day of the week. So just counting back seven days won't work. The most recent week to be totalled might have 4 or 5 entries to sum, or only 1 or 2. Sum each week Wednesday through Tuesday not including last Tuesday.

Below works, but w/o the fixed range. Or count Tuesday but only keep the most recent Tuesday to eliminate last Tuesday.

=SUMPRODUCT(F421:F423, (B421:B423="Wed"
)+(B421:B423="thu")+(B421:B423="fri")+(B421:B423="sat")+(B421:B423="sun")+(B421:B423="mon")+(B421:B423="tue"))

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKNUM(C370:C423+0,13)=C426),F370:F423)
```

Comment: Is this meant to be further detail for your question?